# Java Server sending messages client after closing

Tags: java, swing, sockets, tcp, event-dispatch-thread

I need some help with this code. It's about a Server that suppose to echo the messages from the client back to the client and close after the client types "BYE". But messages only appear on the client after the server is closed.

I will be grateful if I can get the solution to this problem

This the code on the Server side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EchoServer extends JFrame{

   private JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new EchoServer();  
}

public EchoServer(){

   setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);

   setTitle("Server");
   setSize(500, 300);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setVisible(true);

   try {

     //Creating Server socket  

     ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(5000);

    //Display messge to show the server has bean running
    jta.append("Echo Server Started" + '\n');
    /*This is a blocking Statement
    *The program comes to a stand still until the ACCEPT method returns
          */

    Socket incoming = s.accept(); 

    jta.append("Connected to: " + incoming.getInetAddress() +
                     " at port: " + incoming.getLocalPort() + '\n' + '\n'); 



    BufferedReader in 
      = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream())); 
    PrintWriter out 
       = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(), true); 


    //Display welcome message

     out.println("Hi my SERVER. Enter BYE to exit."); 


     for (;;) {
       String str = in.readLine(); 
       if (str == null) {
         break; 
       } else {

          //Display information from Client  

          out.println("Echo: " + str); 


          jta.append("Received: " + str + '\n');

          if (str.trim().equals("BYE")) 
          break; 
      }
    }
    //incoming.close(); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
     jta.append("Error: " + e); 
    }

    jta.append("EchoServer stopped."); 
  }

}
```

And This is the code on the Client side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Client extends JFrame {

private JTextField jtf = new JTextField();

private JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();

private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;

public static void main(String[] args){

    new Client();
}

public Client(){

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JLabel("Enter Text:"), BorderLayout.WEST);
    p.add(jtf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jtf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jtf.addActionListener(new TextFieldListener());

    setTitle("Client");
    setSize(500, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    try {

        //creating a socket

        Socket socket= new Socket("localhost", 5000);


        in = new 
            BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        out = new 
            PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        jta.append(ex.toString() + '\n');
    }
}

private class TextFieldListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       try{
          while (true){                

                String str= in.readLine();

                if (str == null) {

                    //break out of loop

                    break;
                } else {

                    //Display input from server
                    jta.append(str  + "\n");


                    /*enable user to in the text that 
                        will be sent ot the server
                    */
                    String sms = jtf.getText().trim();

                    if ("BYE".equals(sms)){

                        /*if the user types "BYE" send it to the server
                            and break out of the loop
                        */

                        out.println("BYE");

                        break;
                    }

                    //send messages to the server
                    out.println("line " + sms);

                } 
          }
       }
       catch (IOException ex) {
           System.err.println(ex);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a Swing threading issue. Your `while (true)` is blocking the Swing event thread freezing your program. Read on use of background threads, in particular a SwingWorker thread so you can avoid this problem. Start with the [Concurrency in Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

You're also starting your reading only after the user types something, and then sending the same String to the server over and over.

I suggest:

- Use a background thread or SwingWorker to read from the server in the client. This should be set up in the client's constructor, not in the ActionListener.
- Make sure that you append to the client's text area *on* the Swing event thread or EDT. A SwingWorker will help you do this via the publish/process method pair.
- The ActionListener should be much simpler. All it should do is get the JTextField's text and send it to your `out` field via `out.println(...)`.
- Again, do not have `out.println("line " + sms);` inside of a `while (true)` loop, not unless you want to send the same String to the server over and over and over again. Again, this should be in the ActionListener and should be a one shot deal, not called in a loop, but only when the listener is performed.

For example, the ActionListener could be as simple as:

```
private class TextFieldListener implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     String sms = jtf.getText().trim();
     out.println("line " + sms);
  }
}
```

And in the Client constructor:

```
  try {
     Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
     in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

     // !!
     new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           try {
              while (true) {
                 final String str = in.readLine();
                 if (str == null) {
                    break;
                 } else {

                    // ***** call Swing code on the Swing event thread:
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                          jta.append(str + "\n");
                       }
                    });

                    // String sms = jtf.getText().trim();
                    // if ("BYE".equals(sms)) {
                    //    out.println("BYE");
                    //    break;
                    // }
                    // ***** don't call this here!!! *****
                    // out.println("line " + sms);
                 }
              }
           } catch (IOException ex) {
              System.err.println(ex);
           }
        }
     }).start();

     out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     jta.append(ex.toString() + '\n');
  }
```