# Why does my Client freeze when awaiting a response from the Server?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, serversocket

I have two separate Java projects, one a client and one a server. The server is set up to take specific commands from a client and respond to the command depending on what it is.

The following is the connection portion of the client:

```
private class Controller implements ActionListener {
    private final long SLEEP_TIME = 100L;
    private PrintWriter pw;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private Socket socket;
    private static final String serverPrompt = "SERVER>";
    private static final String clientPrompt = "CLIENT>";

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (source instanceof JButton) {
            if (command.equals("Send")) {
                if (socket != null) {
                    String fromServer = null;
                    try {
                        pw.println(commandTextField.getText());
                        try {
                            System.out.println("HERE!");
                            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                            ie.printStackTrace();
                        } // end catch
                        while ((fromServer = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.printf("RECEIVED COMMAND %s\n", fromServer);
                            if (fromServer.startsWith("END"))
                                break;
                            if (fromServer.startsWith("CLS"))
                                terminalTextArea.setText("");
                            if (fromServer.startsWith("?")) {
                                String s = null;
                                br.readLine();
                                terminalTextArea.append(serverPrompt + br.readLine() + "\n");
                                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                    terminalTextArea.append(s + "\n");
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                terminalTextArea.append(serverPrompt + fromServer);
                                //terminalTextArea.append(bw.readLine());
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally { // start finally block
                        try {
                            fromServer = br.readLine();
                            terminalTextArea.append(serverPrompt + fromServer);
                            terminalTextArea.append(clientPrompt + fromServer);
                            pw.close(); // close the output stream
                            br.close(); // close the input stream
                        } catch (IOException ioex) { // closing the resources fails
                            ioex.printStackTrace();
                        } // end catch block
                    } // end finally block
                } else {
                    terminalTextArea.append(clientPrompt + "ERROR: Connection refused: server is not available. Check port or restart server.");
                }
            }
        }
        if (command.equals("Connect")) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(hostTextField.getText(), portComboBox.getItemAt(portComboBox.getSelectedIndex()));
                terminalTextArea.setText("Connecting to a client Socket[addr=" + socket.getInetAddress().toString()
                         + ",port=" + socket.getPort() + ",localport=" + socket.getLocalPort() + "]\n");
                pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                sendButton.setEnabled(true);
                connectButton.setEnabled(false);
                connectButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            } catch (UnknownHostException uhex) {
                uhex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioex) {
                ioex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The GUI for the client is built already and works as I intend it to. `connectionButton` is a private field `JButton` reference and `sendButton` is likewise. The `sendButton` sends the command to the server using the established socket. I would then like the client to listen to a response from the server.

The server code for the connection looks like this:

```
public class ServerSocketRunnable implements Runnable { // start class ServerSocketRunnable
    private final long SLEEP_TIME = 100L;
    private String command;
    private String fullCommand;
    private String[] commands = { "END", "ECHO", "TIME", "DATE", "?", "CLS" };
    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter pw;
    private BufferedReader br;

    public ServerSocketRunnable(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { // start run()
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.printf("Connecting to a client Socket[addr=%s,port=%d,localport=%d]\n",
                    socket.getInetAddress().toString(), socket.getPort(), socket.getLocalPort());
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            while ((fullCommand = br.readLine()) != null) {
                int index = fullCommand.indexOf(">");
                if (index >= 0)
                    command = fullCommand.substring(0, index);
                else
                    command = fullCommand;
                System.out.printf("COMMAND: %s", command);
                switch (command) { // start switch
                case "ECHO": // repeat sent command back to Client
                    String optString = fullCommand.substring(fullCommand.indexOf(">") + 1, fullCommand.length());
                    pw.print(command);
                    pw.printf(": %s\n", optString.trim());
                    break;
                case "TIME": // time command
                    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
                    pw.print(command);
                    pw.printf(": %s\n", timeFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                    break;
                case "DATE": // date command
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy");
                    pw.print(command);
                    pw.printf(": %s\n", dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                    break;
                case "?": // help command
                    pw.print(command);
                    pw.println("AVAILABLE SERVICES:");
                    for (String c : commands) {
                        pw.println(c);
                    }
                    break;
                case "CLS": // clear command
                    pw.println(command);
                    break;
                case "END": // end command
                    pw.println(command);
                    break;
                default: // command received from Client was not valid
                    pw.println("ERROR: Unrecognized command.");
                    break;
                } // end switch
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                } // end catch
            } // end while
        } catch (IOException ioex) { // communication with the Client fails
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        } // end catch block
        finally { // start finally block
            try {
                pw.println("Connection closed");
                pw.close(); // close the output stream
                br.close(); // close the input stream
            } catch (IOException ioex) { // closing the resources fails
                ioex.printStackTrace();
            } // end catch block
        } // end finally block
    } // end run()
} // end class ServerSocketRunnable
```

The server already returns the proper information to the client, except the `?` command which only returns the command and `AVAILABLE SERVICES`. The `?` command should also return the data in the `commands` array. The `END` command is also kind of weird, as it is supposed to terminate the connection after the server acknowledges the `END` from the client.

I also experience the client hanging when it is waiting for a server response. The GUI becomes completely unresponsive and I have to force close it to try another test. Can anybody tell me why my client is becoming unresponsive? I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: Don't make hanging calls on the EDT.  Use a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: @jtahlborn What types would a SwingWorker class in this context use? I'd assume I'd be returning the `String` commands? And processing `String` data as well? So I'd declare a class extending `SwingWorker<String, String>`, since `SwingWorker` is abstract?

Comment: Check the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) or just search this site for [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20socket%20freezes%20body%3aswingworker) (please check the links).

Comment: [Link to another similar question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19552923/522444).